# Parsing XML with .contents() function. How?

Tags: jquery, xml

I am working with the following code to traverse an XML tree no matter how deep it may be. The problem is it only returns the very first root node GetArchive. Like.. its tag name and that is all. What am I missing?

```
$.get('getArchive.xml', null, function (data) {

               var ul = $('<ul/>').fadeIn(1000).appendTo('#GetArchive');

       var JanEntries = $(data).find('GetArchive Y2011 Jan Entry').each( function(){

    var JanEntryId    = $(this).find("janeid").text();    ul.append('<li>' + JanEntryId    + '</li>');  
    var JanEntryDate  = $(this).find("janedate").text();  ul.append('<li>' + JanEntryDate  + '</li>');   
    var JanEntryTime  = $(this).find("janetime").text();  ul.append('<li>' + JanEntryTime  + '</li>');  
    var JanEntrytitle = $(this).find("janetitle").text(); ul.append('<li>' + JanEntrytitle + '</li>');  
    var JanEntryBody  = $(this).find("janebody").text();  ul.append('<li>' + JanEntryBody  + '</li>');  

    $(this).find("Comment").each(function () { 
    var CommentId     = $(this).find("cid").text();   ul.append('<li>' + CommentId   + '</li>');
    var CommentDate   = $(this).find("cdate").text(); ul.append('<li>' + CommentDate + '</li>');
    var CommentTime   = $(this).find("ctime").text(); ul.append('<li>' + CommentTime + '</li>');
    var CommentFrom   = $(this).find("cfrom").text(); ul.append('<li>' + CommentFrom + '</li>');
    var CommentBody   = $(this).find("cbody").text(); ul.append('<li>' + CommentBody + '</li>');  
    });  

});

               var ul = $('<ul/>').fadeIn(1000).appendTo('#GetArchive');

       var FebEntries = $(data).find('GetArchive Y2011 Feb Entry').each( function(){

    var FebEntryId    = $(this).find("febeid").text();    ul.append('<li>' + FebEntryId    + '</li>');  
    var FebEntryDate  = $(this).find("febedate").text();  ul.append('<li>' + FebEntryDate  + '</li>');   
    var FebEntryTime  = $(this).find("febetime").text();  ul.append('<li>' + FebEntryTime  + '</li>');  
    var FebEntrytitle = $(this).find("febetitle").text(); ul.append('<li>' + FebEntrytitle + '</li>');  
    var FebEntryBody  = $(this).find("febebody").text();  ul.append('<li>' + FebEntryBody  + '</li>');  

    $(this).find("Comment").each(function () { 
    var CommentId     = $(this).find("cid").text();   ul.append('<li>' + CommentId   + '</li>');
    var CommentDate   = $(this).find("cdate").text(); ul.append('<li>' + CommentDate + '</li>');
    var CommentTime   = $(this).find("ctime").text(); ul.append('<li>' + CommentTime + '</li>');
    var CommentFrom   = $(this).find("cfrom").text(); ul.append('<li>' + CommentFrom + '</li>');
    var CommentBody   = $(this).find("cbody").text(); ul.append('<li>' + CommentBody + '</li>');  
    });  

});

}, 'xml');
```

**Here is my XML structure.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GetArchive>
  <Y2012>
    <Jan>
      <Entry>
        <janeid>&lt;b&gt;Jan Entry ID 1&lt;/b&gt;</janeid>
        <janedate>entry date</janedate>
        <janetime>entry time</janetime>
        <janetitle>entry title</janetitle>
        <janebody>entry &lt;b&gt;body&lt;/b&gt;! html friendly</janebody>
        <Comments>
          <Comment>
            <cid>Jan Comment ID 1</cid>
            <cdate>comment date</cdate>
            <ctime>comment time</ctime>
            <cfrom>comment from</cfrom>
            <cbody>comment body! text only</cbody>
          </Comment>
          <Comment>
            <cid>Jan Comment ID 2</cid>
            <cdate>comment date</cdate>
            <ctime>comment time</ctime>
            <cfrom>comment from</cfrom>
            <cbody>comment body! text only</cbody>
          </Comment>
        </Comments>
      </Entry>
      <Entry>
        <janeid>&lt;b&gt;Jan Entry ID 2&lt;/b&gt;</janeid>
        <janedate>entry date</janedate>
        <janetime>entry time</janetime>
        <janetitle>entry title</janetitle>
        <janebody>entry &lt;b&gt;body&lt;/b&gt;! html friendly</janebody>
        <Comments>
          <Comment>
            <cid>Jan Comment ID 3</cid>
            <cdate>comment date</cdate>
            <ctime>comment time</ctime>
            <cfrom>comment from</cfrom>
            <cbody>comment body! text only</cbody>
          </Comment>
          <Comment>
            <cid>Jan Comment ID 4</cid>
            <cdate>comment date</cdate>
            <ctime>comment time</ctime>
            <cfrom>comment from</cfrom>
            <cbody>comment body! text only</cbody>
          </Comment>
        </Comments>
      </Entry>
    </Jan>
    <Feb>
      <Entry>
        <febeid>&lt;b&gt;Feb Entry ID 1&lt;/b&gt;</febeid>
        <febedate>entry date</febedate>
        <febetime>entry time</febetime>
        <febetitle>entry title</febetitle>
        <febebody>entry &lt;b&gt;body&lt;/b&gt;! html friendly</febebody>
        <Comments>
          <Comment>
            <cid>Feb Comment ID 1</cid>
            <cdate>comment date</cdate>
            <ctime>comment time</ctime>
            <cfrom>comment from</cfrom>
            <cbody>comment body! text only</cbody>
          </Comment>
          <Comment>
            <cid>Feb Comment ID 2</cid>
            <cdate>comment date</cdate>
            <ctime>comment time</ctime>
            <cfrom>comment from</cfrom>
            <cbody>comment body! text only</cbody>
          </Comment>
        </Comments>
      </Entry>
      <Entry>
        <febeid>&lt;b&gt;Feb Entry ID 2&lt;/b&gt;</febeid>
        <febedate>entry date</febedate>
        <febetime>entry time</febetime>
        <febetitle>entry title</febetitle>
        <febebody>entry &lt;b&gt;body&lt;/b&gt;! html friendly</febebody>
        <Comments>
          <Comment>
            <cid>Feb Comment ID 3</cid>
            <cdate>comment date</cdate>
            <ctime>comment time</ctime>
            <cfrom>comment from</cfrom>
            <cbody>comment body! text only</cbody>
          </Comment>
          <Comment>
            <cid>Feb Comment ID 4</cid>
            <cdate>comment date</cdate>
            <ctime>comment time</ctime>
            <cfrom>comment from</cfrom>
            <cbody>comment body! text only</cbody>
          </Comment>
        </Comments>
      </Entry>
    </Feb>
  </Y2012>
  <Y2011>
    <Jan>
      <Entry>
        <janeid>&lt;b&gt;Jan Entry ID 1&lt;/b&gt;</janeid>
        <janedate>entry date</janedate>
        <janetime>entry time</janetime>
        <janetitle>entry title</janetitle>
        <janebody>entry &lt;b&gt;body&lt;/b&gt;! html friendly</janebody>
        <Comments>
          <Comment>
            <cid>Jan Comment ID 1</cid>
            <cdate>comment date</cdate>
            <ctime>comment time</ctime>
            <cfrom>comment from</cfrom>
            <cbody>comment body! text only</cbody>
          </Comment>
          <Comment>
            <cid>Jan Comment ID 2</cid>
            <cdate>comment date</cdate>
            <ctime>comment time</ctime>
            <cfrom>comment from</cfrom>
            <cbody>comment body! text only</cbody>
          </Comment>
        </Comments>
      </Entry>
      <Entry>
        <janeid>&lt;b&gt;Jan Entry ID 2&lt;/b&gt;</janeid>
        <janedate>entry date</janedate>
        <janetime>entry time</janetime>
        <janetitle>entry title</janetitle>
        <janebody>entry &lt;b&gt;body&lt;/b&gt;! html friendly</janebody>
        <Comments>
          <Comment>
            <cid>Jan Comment ID 3</cid>
            <cdate>comment date</cdate>
            <ctime>comment time</ctime>
            <cfrom>comment from</cfrom>
            <cbody>comment body! text only</cbody>
          </Comment>
          <Comment>
            <cid>Jan Comment ID 4</cid>
            <cdate>comment date</cdate>
            <ctime>comment time</ctime>
            <cfrom>comment from</cfrom>
            <cbody>comment body! text only</cbody>
          </Comment>
        </Comments>
      </Entry>
    </Jan>
    <Feb>
      <Entry>
        <febeid>&lt;b&gt;Feb Entry ID 1&lt;/b&gt;</febeid>
        <febedate>entry date</febedate>
        <febetime>entry time</febetime>
        <febetitle>entry title</febetitle>
        <febebody>entry &lt;b&gt;body&lt;/b&gt;! html friendly</febebody>
        <Comments>
          <Comment>
            <cid>Feb Comment ID 1</cid>
            <cdate>comment date</cdate>
            <ctime>comment time</ctime>
            <cfrom>comment from</cfrom>
            <cbody>comment body! text only</cbody>
          </Comment>
          <Comment>
            <cid>Feb Comment ID 2</cid>
            <cdate>comment date</cdate>
            <ctime>comment time</ctime>
            <cfrom>comment from</cfrom>
            <cbody>comment body! text only</cbody>
          </Comment>
        </Comments>
      </Entry>
      <Entry>
        <febeid>&lt;b&gt;Feb Entry ID 2&lt;/b&gt;</febeid>
        <febedate>entry date</febedate>
        <febetime>entry time</febetime>
        <febetitle>entry title</febetitle>
        <febebody>entry &lt;b&gt;body&lt;/b&gt;! html friendly</febebody>
        <Comments>
          <Comment>
            <cid>Feb Comment ID 3</cid>
            <cdate>comment date</cdate>
            <ctime>comment time</ctime>
            <cfrom>comment from</cfrom>
            <cbody>comment body! text only</cbody>
          </Comment>
          <Comment>
            <cid>Feb Comment ID 4</cid>
            <cdate>comment date</cdate>
            <ctime>comment time</ctime>
            <cfrom>comment from</cfrom>
            <cbody>comment body! text only</cbody>
          </Comment>
        </Comments>
      </Entry>
    </Feb>
  </Y2011>
</GetArchive>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having a tough time understanding exactly what you're trying to do, but something along these lines might get you started:

```
//custom function to return all text nodes
$.fn.textNodes = function(){
    return $(this).contents().filter(function(){ 
        return this.nodeType == 3 || this.nodeName == "BR"; 
    });
}

// append all text nodes to list
ul.append($(data).textNodes().wrap("<li/>"));
```

**EDIT** : `<li>` elements aren't being created. Here are a few alternatives to try:

```
ul.append($(data).textNodes().wrap("<li>");

ul.append($(data).textNodes().wrap("<li></li>");

ul.append($(data).textNodes().wrap(function(){
    return "<li>" + $(this).text() + "</li>";
});
```

Here's another version of the `textNodes` function:

```
//custom function to return all text nodes
$.fn.textNodes = function() {
    var ret = [];
    this.each( function() {
        var fn = arguments.callee;
        $(this).contents().each( function() {
            if ( this.nodeType == 3 || $.nodeName(this, "br") ) 
            ret.push(this);
            else fn.apply($(this));
        });
    });
    return $(ret);
}
```

Comment: Basically I am trying to make this code so dynamic that there should be no need to specify a node name and loop through it.

Comment: Would the first solution accomplish what you're looking for?

Comment: Wow! It is 99% working! It seems that although all data is being added to <ul> the list tags for each node <li> do not appear in the source. Minor fix?

Comment: Hmm... should be an easy fix. Probably just need to tweak `ul.append($(data).textNodes().wrap("<li/>"));`

Comment: James, I don't mean to be a pain but is there a way to create the nodes on the fly instead of pushing them into an array? Just curious.

Comment: What do you mean? The first solution doesn't put them into an array. The second solution does though.

Comment: I have edited the original. It's fully function and you can see the desired output.

Comment: So you ended up just finding each node manually, instead of traversing it dynamically?

Comment: ..which is exactly what I am trying to improve.

Comment: What's the problem with parsing it using JSON?

Comment: Basically I've never used it and also the results do not display on screen as html.

Comment: It will probably just require a little tweaking to get the HTML right.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate that. I've been fiddling around with it from my end. If I'm able to get it working right, I'll update my answer and shoot you a message.